# How to make android app for existing dynamic website

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, sql

I want to develop an android app like olx, and quikr for one of my website, [Fusion120](http://www.fusion120.com/). Front end of website is in html, css, javascript, jquery and back end uses php and sql server. I don't know where and  how to start, please Gide me.

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. In its current form your question is unanswerable, because it is much too broad. Please gather extra information and then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27615803/edit) your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to can webview in android app when icon is click

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    WebView mwebview;
    ProgressDialog barProgressDialog;
    ConnectionDetector cd;
    Boolean status;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);       

        String myurl = "http://www.fusion120.com";


        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(myurl);

    }   
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

database which you use in the website can be exposed to other mobile devices and other applications via web services or REST services.

service development is depend on which technology, program language you going to use etc...

try this link

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

i hope your work is done by this answer

Answer (score 0):

[PhoneGap SDK](http://phonegap.com/) is very useful to make app using HTML, jquery-mobile and web-services. You can go for it and have a look at the tutorials. Very basic knowledge of android is enough to make your site in Android.